# Charset.forName() cannot resolve symbol "CP-437". How do I use this Charset?

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream

I'm writing a parser for a txt file I get from my customer. Apparently the charset I'm using is not correct as some characters are not displayed correctly.

I tried `file -I file.txt` but I get `file.txt: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit`

I tried different charset settings on an editor and with **DOS (CP 437)** everything looks good.

So I'm trying to read the file with this charset but get the error *"cannot resolve symbol"* when using

```
Charset.forName("CP-437")
```

(java.nio.charset.Charset)

I also tried different spellings but nothing worked so far. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `IBM437` (for `nio` packages), so  :

```
Charset.forName("IBM437");
```

Look at this link for the supported encodings :

[Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 3):

The answer goes somewhat like this :

```
public class Charsets {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedMap<String, Charset> x = Charset.availableCharsets();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x.containsKey("CP-437"));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. In the end it was a naming issue, but this is useful to check which charsets are available.